# does ASP .Net SqlMembershipProvider work with SQL Azure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I have [read](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/08/16/migration-for-user-accounts-from-the-sqlmembershipprovider-to-the-universal-providers/) that SqlMembershipProvider doesn't work with SQL Azure, but I am currently using it.  I initially encountered some issues, but I am able to login to the site and access role information.

So what is the deal?  Do only certain parts of SqlMembershipProvider not work with SQL Azure?

Comment: You referenced an article from over 4 years ago. That's not relevant anymore.

Comment: SqlMembershipProvider is over 10 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, it had some issues with schema and SQL Azure Migration tool. It was why **ASP.NET Universal Providers** was created.

**Simple Membership Provider** later replaced ASP.NET Universal Providers.

Now, **ASP.Net Identity** replaced all those.